# Creating Thumbnail Preview like Powerpoint thumnails in wpf

Tags: wpf, prism

I have a wpf application with two panes similar to powerpoint application:

- left pane which shows list of all the panels in listbox
- right pane which shows the selected panel

In the listbox I want to display panel as thumbnail and update the thumbnail as an when new controls are added to panel in right pane.

Just like powerpoint application thumbnail behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `RenderTargetBitmap` and `PngBitmapEncoder` we can capture a region of window.
and by using the `PngBitmapEncoder` frame Property assigned it to Image Source.

Lets start with Xaml

I divided the window by two half and left and right panel. Same in PowerPoint with less style. In order to demonstrate I have implemented to add `TextBox` on the right panel and the preview will be displayed on the left panel thumbnail.

```
    <Grid Background="Aqua" x:Name="gridg">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="372" Margin="10,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="306" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Listtems" SelectionChanged="Listtems_SelectionChanged" />

    <Button Content="+ TextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Background="Wheat" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="321,0,0,0"  />
    </Grid>
```

[image]

As soon as you click on the left panel item, the corresponding the control will be displayed on the right panel with the data.

In order to keep track of the items in the `ListBox`, I have used `Dictionary` with `ItemIndex` and to it's corresponding item's index used control.

Window's Code Behind

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window6.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Window6 : Window
{
    Dictionary<int, Control> _dictionaryControls = new Dictionary<int, Control>();
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    public Window6()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }


    private void BmpImage()
    {
        RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap =
        new RenderTargetBitmap(800, 450, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        renderTargetBitmap.Render(stackPanel);
        PngBitmapEncoder pngImage = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        pngImage.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));

        Image img = new Image();
        img.Source = pngImage.Frames[0];
        img.Height = 148;
        img.Width = 222;
        Listtems.Items.Add(img);
        Listtems.SelectedIndex = Listtems.Items.Count - 1;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        stackPanel.Children.Clear();
        int item = Listtems.Items.Count;
        TextBox txtControl = new TextBox();
        txtControl.FontSize = 100;
        txtControl.Height = 122;
        txtControl.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        _dictionaryControls.Add(item, txtControl);
        stackPanel.Children.Add(txtControl);
        stackPanel.UpdateLayout();
        BmpImage();
    }

    private void Listtems_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateThumbNail();
    }

    private void UpdateThumbNail()
    {
        int indexbackup = -1;
        Listtems.SelectionChanged -= Listtems_SelectionChanged;
        Control control;

        _dictionaryControls.TryGetValue(Listtems.SelectedIndex, out control);
        if (control == null)
        {
            Listtems.SelectionChanged += Listtems_SelectionChanged;
            return;
        }

        indexbackup = Listtems.SelectedIndex;

        stackPanel.Children.Clear();
        stackPanel.Children.Add(control);
        stackPanel.UpdateLayout();

        RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap =
            new RenderTargetBitmap(800, 450, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        renderTargetBitmap.Render(stackPanel);
        PngBitmapEncoder pngImage = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        pngImage.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));

        Image img = new Image();
        img.Source = pngImage.Frames[0];
        img.Height = 148;
        img.Width = 222;

        Listtems.Items.Insert(Listtems.SelectedIndex, img);
        Listtems.Items.RemoveAt(Listtems.SelectedIndex);

        Listtems.SelectedIndex = indexbackup;
        Listtems.SelectionChanged += Listtems_SelectionChanged;

    }


    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateThumbNail();
    }
}
```

**BmpImage**() : - I used to capture or in other words the print screen of the `StackPanel` control.

**Button_Click Event** :- Is used to create a new Item in `ListBox` adding Image with the current print screen of the `TextBox` Control in `StackPanel`. It also adds control in **_dictionaryControls** variable.

**Listtems_SelectionChanged Event**:- Clears the `StackPanel` and  then take the `TextBox` Control from **_dictionaryControls** based on the SelectedIndex of ListBox and place it in the `StackPanel` by taking current snapshot of the `StackPanel`.

For Demo Purpose, I have done it only for `TextBox` Control, but you can do it for any other control with a little tweaking.

**UpdateThumbNail** created a method responsible to update the image in Listbox based on the ListBoxItem.

**dispatcherTimer_Tick** : - Event is responsible to call the UpdateThumbNail() Method for every second.

Comment: Hi Satish, thanks for your guided and detail solution.One question with your solution how to achieve scenario- when user is editing the text box title by typing "f" after "second" the thumbnail will also display "f". Like power point thumbnail behavior.

Comment: @Sharda  Updated my answer, this will update your thumb nail in run time.